# Worker thread update ObservableCollection that is bound to a ListCollectionView (.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I found the solution for updating observable collection from worker thread.
[Link to the solution](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx)
But some times I get the following error:

“An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.
  See the inner exception for more information.”

Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:13' with name 'CAListBox' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
  Accumulated count 12 is different from actual count 13.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
     System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
      System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
       System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView
  *     Sample.ViewModel.ObservableCollectionEx`1[[Sample.ViewModel.Message, Sample.ViewModel, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

I researched and found solution which will only work for .NET 4.5 and not .NET 4.0. 
I am using .NET 4.0 visual studio 2010. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're updating the collection, just switch it over so it updates in the UI Thread.  You can do that by using the Dispatcher.

```
// Other code here...

// Now update the collection in the UI Thread.  Use BeginInvoke if it needs to be Async
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action(() => 
        {
             // Add to the collection here
             foreach (object myObject in myObjects)
             {
                 this.myCollection.Add(myObject);
             }
        }));

// Any other code needed here...
```